# Insert row or update if exists (multiple conditions if exists)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a row that contains 3 fields:
day earnings person
1      3        1
1      7        2
1      4        3
2      6        1
2      9        2

The idea is that every person earns money/day, now what I want is to update the earnings for a day for a person, but if that person didn't have any earnings (the row for that person/day is not there) than insert the row

Example
day earnings person
1      3       1

In this case, it would update the row and add 1 earning:
day earnings person
1      4       1

If the original row was not preasent (so person and date did not exist) than insert a new row like:
day earnings person
1      1       1

I know that there exists the command INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

But this works only for 1 unique index column (from what I read), I need it to work with day and person (2 columns).

I hope I explained correctly and someone can help. 
 I know it's possible to do this from PHP but to avoid multiple queries (it's important) I would like to know if it's possible to make it in 1 query.

Here is what works if I only consider the date column (that is unique)
 any chance I can change it to work in my case?

```
INSERT INTO table (day, earnings, person)
VALUES ('1',earnings,1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
earnings = VALUES(earnings+1)
```

Comment: Let me throw this link out there with a quick answer until you get a more thorough one below: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/02/21/flexible-insert-and-update-in-mysql/

Comment: I'm not sure I can think of any solution that doesn't require multiple queries either with PHP (check for existence then do the update, otherwise insert) or writing a procedure (again multiple queries) in MySQL, I might be wrong.

Comment: Have you tried creating a compound index that includes both fields? I'm not certain, but pretty positive that it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make it work by adding a composite unique key on both day and person.

```
ALTER TABLE `myTable` ADD UNIQUE (`day`,`person`);
```

And then

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (day, earnings, person)
VALUES ('1',$earnings,1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
earnings = earnings + $earnings
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me I am not the best with mysql, skipped the classes when in college on this one :) Fortunately for me is that I have stackoverflow. Thank you very much piotrm for your answer, it's perfect!!!!!